# A few definite integrals

Tags: integration

a) $\displaystyle \int_{-1}^0 x \sqrt{2 - 5x}dx. $

I think I should use some change of variables here, but it didn't work the way I tried to use it.

b) $\displaystyle \int_{0}^{2} \frac{1}{(x + 2)(x + 3)}dx.$

Comment: $\frac{1}{(x+2)(x+3)}=\frac{A}{x+2}+\frac{B}{x+3}$, partial fraction decomposition

Comment: a) Substitute $u=2-5x$. b) Partial fractions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per Mitra:

$u=2-5x \iff du=-5\,dx$,

$$\therefore \int_{-1}^{0} x\sqrt{2-5x} \, dx=\int_{-1}^{0}\frac{u-2}{-5}\sqrt{u}\frac{1}{-5} \, du.$$

$$
\frac{1}{(x+2)(x+3)}=\frac{1}{x+2}+\frac{-1}{x+3}.
$$

$$\therefore \int_0^2 \frac{1}{(x+2)(x+3)} \, dx=\int_0^2\frac{1}{x+2} \, dx-\int_0^2 \frac{1}{x+3}.$$

Comment: Thanks a lot! So we have $log(6/5)$ in the second one..

Comment: @Michael, indeed. Have a good day.

Answer (score 0):

Another way is by a rationalizing substitution:
$$
\begin{align}
u & = \sqrt{2-5x} \\[8pt]
u^2 & = 2 - 5x \\[8pt]
2u\,du & = -5\,dx \\[8pt]
\frac{-2}{5} u \, du & = dx \\[8pt]
x & = \frac{2-u^2}{5}
\end{align}
$$
When $x=-1$ then $u=\sqrt{7}$ and when $x=0$ then $u=\sqrt{2}$.  So
$$
\int_{-1}^0 x \sqrt{2-5x} \, dx = \int_\sqrt{7}^\sqrt{2} \frac{2-u^2}{5}\cdot u\left(\frac{-2}{5} u\, du \right) = \frac{4}{25}\int_\sqrt{2}^\sqrt{7}(2u^2-u^4)\,du
$$